# javascript array merge based on indexes

Tags: javascript

I have one array, needs to merge with values the same indexes values like 0 will become `['0','0','1','2']`

Example:

```
0:
    0: (2) ['0', '0']
    1: (2) ['0', '0']
    2: (2) ['0', '2']
1:  
    0: ['1']
    1: ['2']
    2: ['2']
2:  
    0: ['2']
    1: ['2']
    2: ['2']
```

Tried

```
var result = outterArray.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.map(function (v, i) {
            return [v] + b[i];
        });
      });
```

but getting

```
0: "0,012"
1: "0,022"
2: "0,222"
```

expected :

```
0: "[0,0,1,2]"
1: "[0,0,2,2]"
2: "[0,2,2,2]"
```

Comment: what goes wrong? please add data and your code.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: No clue how you go from that array to the example output.

Comment: Please be a little more detailed: what is input here, and what is output? Also, what code did you already write and isn't doing what you expected it to? If it's been a while, please remember to reread [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and then update your post accordingly.

Comment: Is the original data always a square? (same number of rows as columns) If not, is is always rectangular (same number of columns in each row)

Comment: Not the same, it will be a dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the below array, you could map the inner array and take the values from the accumulator at same index or an empty array.

```js
const 
    data= [
        [['0', '0'], ['0', '0'], ['0', '2']],
        [['1'], ['2'], ['2']],
        [['2'], ['2'], ['2']]
    ],
    result = data.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), ...v]), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```